# Developer guide for Kafka and Scala integration

Tags: scala, message-queue, apache-kafka

I'm researching on Kafka to apply in to my project. My project is written in Scala. Unfortunately, I can not find any good material for how to use Kafka in Scala. Could anyone give me a hint on any tutorial or repository to learn about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally in this case, the best think is looking at the official sources, take a look at thiw two tutorials from typesafe:

[hello-kafka](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/hello-kafka)
[reactive kafka](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/reactive-kafka-scala)

and also in the official site the is a quickstart:

[kafka intro](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction)

Finally take a look at this repo in github: it has talso a virtual machine, to use:

[github sample](https://github.com/stealthly/scala-kafka)